# Firebase Dynamic Links not working if the app is running in the background iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have setup Firebase Dynamic Links for my iOS app and I'm encountering issues with only one scenario on iOS 13:

- If the app is already running/opened in the background, and the deeplink is clicked my app opens up but doesn't handle a deeplink -> not a single callback method that handles deeplink is being triggered.

So, other 2 scenarios are working properly:

- If user doesn't have an app, the app gets installed and handles the deeplink properly inside my *AppDelegate*
- If the app is closed, clicking on the deeplink opens up the app and my callback method is getting triggered in my *SceneDelegate*

Which callback method is supposed to be triggered for the scenario when app is already running in the background?

So far I have implemented these:
*App delegate*

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
               restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
```

*SceneDelegate*

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity)
```

From what I can see in the logs only the the first method in the SceneDelegate is getting called, the other two never.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Milos

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by removing SceneDelegate completely and relying only on the 3 mentioned functions of the *AppDelegate*.